# mySQL: выбрать top-100 записей, которые повторяются n-раз

Tags: mysql

Как выбрать TOP-100 записей, где entry_id повторяется более 3 раз?

```
CREATE TABLE `bookmarks` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `entry_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `date_added` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `user_id_entry_id` (`user_id`, `entry_id`)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так подойдет (для n=3):

```
SELECT *, COUNT(id) FROM bookmarks
GROUP BY entry_id HAVING COUNT(id)>3
ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

Группируем под `entry_id` выбирая только те записи, у которых `COUNT(id)` больше `n` (в нашем примере = 3).
Далее сортируем по кол-ву упоминаний (`COUNT(id)`) в обратном порядке
и берем только 100 записей